# Getting one hour less in time when converting to UTC via moment - utcOffset not working

Tags: momentjs

When converting time to UTC its showing one hour less than expected

I am updating a variable of dot net via moment to convert the time & show local system time to user. But post conversion i am getting one hour less. Tried utcOffset but getting error utcOffset is not a function. any suggestion

Where formData.SubmittedDate = "6/7/2019 5:44:59 AM"

```
$('[data-utcdate]').each(function () {  
    var d = moment($(this).attr('data-utcdate'));
    //var isDST = d.utc().local().isDST();
    //var d = moment(d).utcOffset(d);
    d = d.utc();
    $(this).html(d.format('MMM D, YYYY h:mm A'));
})
```

Getting :Jun 7, 2019 12:14 AM
Expected : Jun 7, 2019 11:44 AM

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Get the UTC offset in minutes.

So you could use a manipulation method like [add](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) with it:

```
$('[data-utcdate]').each(function () {  
    var d = moment($(this).attr('data-utcdate'));
    var offset = d.utcOffset() // will return the offset in minutes
    var time = d.add(offset, "m");
    $(this).html(time.format('MMM D, YYYY h:mm A'));
})
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!!
I am getting error "utcOffset is not a function"

Comment: how do you import moment? Did you try to run my code? Because I do not get that error.

Comment: Yes i have added your code, its added to dotnet build as min file & version is 2.5.1

Comment: have you tried to console log the d variable? Maybe there is some kind of error and it is undefined.

Comment: Yes, d.utcOffse = defined as below


    _d: Fri Jun 07 2019 08:36:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
    _f: undefined
_i: "6/7/2019 8:36:56 AM"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_l: undefined
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
_strict: undefined
__proto__: Object